# How do I run a method from TKinter without having the GUI freeze up?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Supposed I have a method that is run when a button is pressed in TKinter. This method opens up an external application (i.e. Excel, Powerpoint, etc. The application my program opens takes a little longer to open which is why I need the loading dialog)

I am trying to open up a little custom `tk.toplevel` loading dialog that will display and `takefocus` while the external application loads.

However, whenever TKinter runs the method to open the application, the whole thing freezes up and my loading dialog is only visible after the application finally opens.

Is there a way to show my loading dialog while at the same time opening the application in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the same time. Instead open the dialog first and then call the method that opens the other application. You will have to enforce the drawing of the dialog by calling `update_idletasks` before the method that will freeze the GUI, otherwise the dialog won't be drawn until the program is idle and it will be too late.

In this example I used `time.sleep` to simulate a task that keeps the application busy and the GUI frozen.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk


class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self._root = tk.Tk()
        b = tk.Button(self._root, text='Click me', command=self.onclick)
        b.pack()

    def run(self):
        self._root.mainloop()

    def onclick(self):
        dialog = tk.Toplevel(self._root)
        tk.Label(dialog, text='Loading...').pack()
        dialog.update_idletasks()
        self.this_takes_a_long_time()
        dialog.destroy()

    def this_takes_a_long_time(self):
        time.sleep(5)


App().run()
```

Comment: I tried this and the loading dialog still shows up after the application opens. Maybe because both methods are under a `try:` statement? Not sure.

Comment: Reattempted with the `tk.toplevel` called outside of the `try: open_external_application()` statement. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @RBuntu You have to enforce a redrawing of the GUI, see the example.

Comment: I would suggest writing a function and passing it to a thread with the threading module. It worked for me in the past.

Comment: @Goyo Hmm, doesnt seem to be working. Even the exact code you posted for me causes a `toplevel` window to come up but its transparent and frozen, and I cant see the "Loading" label

Comment: @Luke.py I tried that but then I'm not entirely sure how to detect that the application is opened so I can call a `loading_window.destroy()` method, since once its threaded, I'm not sure how to get that operation to interact with the mainloop.

Comment: @RBuntu Weird, works for me using python 3.5.2 in Ubuntu. If the secondary windows disappear after a few seconds it must be a rendering issue. Try `dialog.update()` instead of `dialog.update_idletasks()`.

Comment: @RBuntu I used while thread.is_alive(): or while not thread.is_alive():

Comment: @Luke.py For some reason I get a `WindowsError` error saying `CoInitialize has not been called`